# How to change the language in XFCE 4 on Raspbian

Tags: locale

I installed Raspbian on my Raspberry Pi 2 (Model B).

Since the user that will use it is Italian, I would like to set the language in XFCE4 to Italian. It seems that there is no panel in the settings about internationalization and languages, and so I assumed it has to be done by manually changing some configuration file.

Could please someone guide me through the procedure?

Comment: Should the entire system use Italian? If so you can run sudo raspi-config. It includes several options to change the language (keyboard, locale, time zone etc.)

Comment: I already changed the locale, keymap and time zone. However, this does not change the interface's language. All the menus are still in English.

Comment: stupid question bit did you reboot? This may help as well http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167794/how-to-change-language-interface-in-xfce

Comment: Yes, I did :) Maybe there could be a missing package for XFCE...? I just installed it by doing apt-get...

Comment: I think the answer is to create the file mentioned in the link I shared.